# Linux sed expression to convert the camelCase keys to underscore strings

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I could not get the regex to convert only the key from a key value pair from camel case to underscore sting.

The expressions like *sed -E 's/\B[A-Z]/_\U&/g'* converts the full value, but I would like to limit the conversion only to the key here.

```sh
 $ echo UserPoolId="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c" | sed -E 's/\B[A-Z]/_\U&/g' 
   User_Pool_Id=eu-west-1_6_K6_Q2b_T9c
```

but i would like to get *User_Pool_Id=eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c*

Comment: If it was present in your input should `UserPoolID` become `User_Pool_I_D` or `User_Pool_ID`?

Comment: The left side follows the camel case strategy and so it is always UserPoolId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one `=` sign and you want to modify the camel case before the `=` sign, with GNU `sed` you can iterate until all substitutions are done:

```sh
echo UserPoolId="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c" | sed -E ':a;s/([a-z])([A-Z].*=.*)/\1_\2/;ta'
User_Pool_Id=eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c
```

`:a` sets label `a`, `ta` branches to label `a` if the previous `s` command substituted something. The `s` command in the loop inserts a `_` between a lower case and an upper case **before** the equal sign.

In your example this will first insert a `_` between `User` and `Pool`, and then between `Pool` and `Id`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ echo 'UserPoolId="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c"' |
    awk 'match($0,/([^=]+=)"(.*)"/,a) { $0=gensub(/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/,"\\1_\\2","g",a[1]) a[2]} 1'
User_Pool_Id=eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c
```

I don't know if it's what you'd want for this case or not but anyway:

```
$ echo 'UserPoolID="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c"' |
    awk 'match($0,/([^=]+=)"(.*)"/,a) { $0=gensub(/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/,"\\1_\\2","g",a[1]) a[2]} 1'
User_Pool_ID=eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c
```

Note that `ID` remains as `_ID` and isn't converted to `_I_D`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in `sed` is somewhat challenging because you need a more complex regex and a more complex script. Perhaps a better solution would be to use the shell's substitution facilities to isolate the part you want to operate on.

```
string='UserPoolId="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c"'
prefix=${string%%=*}
suffix=${string#"$prefix"}
sed -E -e 's/\B[A-Z]/_\U&/g' -e "s/\$/$suffix/" <<<"$prefix"
```

Bash also has built-in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to convert the first character of a string to upper case, but perhaps this is sufficient to solve your immediate problem.

Comment: thanks.. i found another solution using awk also : echo UserPoolId="eu-west-1_6K6Q2bT9c" | awk -F= '{gsub(/\B[A-Z]+/,"_&",$1); gsub(OFS,"="); print}'

Comment: @VinothSelvaraj that awk script in your comment would break if your quoted string contained blanks as they'd get replaced with `=`s.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/=/&\n/;h;s/\B[[:upper:]]/_&/g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Introduce a newline after the `=` and copy the result to the hold space.

Insert underscores in the required places.

Append the copy to the current line  and remove the middle, leaving the answer.